# How to make all text bold in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

How I can make all the text bold in Gvim/Macvim editor ? I tried following commands but none of them work.

```
"set guifont=Monospace\ 16
" set guifont=Fixed\Bold 11
" set guifont=Monospace\ Bold\ 20
```

Please give me your suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: Try setting it with `:set guifont=*`.

Comment: Similar: [Is it possible to easily work with .odt, .doc, .docx, .rtf, and other non-plain-text formats in Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/554/467)

Comment: I'm voting to close as this question belongs to: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @svlasov this command does not give me permanent text bold? Is there any way to store it in the .vimrc or .gvimrc file ? Thanks.

Comment: After setting the font with gui dialog, get the setting with `:set guifont?` and copy paste to `.vimrc`.

Comment: Well, :set guifont=? gives me this guifont=Menlo Bold:h15 and if I store it in the .vimrc file with or without set keywords I can not see the permanent changes. Can you show an an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following in .vimrc or .gvimrc file.

```
if has("gui_running")
  if has("gui_gtk2")
    set guifont=Inconsolata\ 12
  elseif has("gui_macvim")
    set guifont=Menlo\ Bold:h14
  elseif has("gui_win32")
    set guifont=Consolas:h11:cANSI
  endif
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`"` means comment, these lines will not be executed. Try adding one of them to `.vimrc` without `"`:

```
set guifont=Monospace\ Bold\ 20
```

To make sure nothing else overrides the font setting, add the line to the end of `.vimrc`.

To get the right string, first use `:set guifont=*` to set the font, then extract the value with `:set guifont?`.